# How do I find the full text of a tweet with json data (in tweepy)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, tweepy

In tweepy I am trying to stream data and I can only get a short amount of text displayed to my screen. I spent 30 minutes trying to find an answer, but none worked. I am just trying to get the full tweet's text, thank you

```
import tweepy
import json
from time import sleep
import requests

# Specify the account credentials in the following variables:
consumer_key = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
access_token = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

# This listener will print out all Tweets it receives
class PrintListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        # Decode the JSON data
        tweet = json.loads(data)

        id = tweet["id"]
        user = tweet['user']['screen_name']
        user_message = tweet['text']

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = PrintListener()

    # Show system message
    print('searching stuff ==>')

    # Authenticate
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    # Connect the stream to our listener
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    # stream.filter(track=['test'])
    stream.filter(track=['test'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not a Retweet, you can use the `extended_tweet` field of the JSON data representing the Tweet and the `full_text` sub-field of that field to get the full text of the Tweet. Otherwise, if it's a Retweet, you'll have to do so with the JSON data representing the Retweeted Tweet, which would be the `retweeted_status` field of the Retweet JSON data. Note, the `extended_tweet` field will only exist for extended Tweets.

I would recommend using the Status object that's passed to `on_status` and the corresponding attributes of that object instead, since you don't seem to be doing anything that requires the raw JSON data.

For further information about extended Tweets, see [Tweepy's documentation on the subject](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extended_tweets.html) and [Twitter's Tweet updates documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates).